# How can I avoid a specific area of raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, extract-by-mask

I have a raster polygon. I need to avoid certain area (another raster) from that raster. I need to avoid a watershed sub basin area that has its area on other basin also. How can I remove that basin?

For example:

I have the raster or shapefile of a country and I also have the shapefile or raster of a state in that country. I need to get the shapefile or raster of the country without the state I have.

I need to mask, but if I extract by mask, it gives the output as the boundary of the layer that we specified, but I need the rest of the area from the input.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to explain what you mean by "avoid" and "remove", please?  I think your question must be about masking and that including a diagram would make what you are asking much clearer.

Comment: actually i need to mask. suppose if extract by mask. it gives the output as the boundary of the layer that we specified, but i need the rest of the area from the input.

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that you can use to improve it with additional details and clarifications like this.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGis this is done through the environment setting of your analysis. See the [mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w0000001t000000) explanation on the link.